# How to retrieve match records across multiple rows and columns in MySQL and suggest replacement

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table :

```
Row 1 : col1    col2    col3    col4    col5 ...etc...

Row 2 : col1    col2    col3    col4    col5 ...etc...

...etc...
```

I want to compare every col on each row to see if in that row is something duplicate.
Example : col1 == col2 or if col1 == col 3 ... etc ... col 2 == col1 ; or col 2 == col 4 etc.

If there's a match on some colomns , I want the code to echo the id of the row and colomns that matches and from an array of multiple options of numbers that i give to select one that is not present in the row and to update there.

In final after running all the rows for each of the i want to see if was unique columns or duplicate.

Example of perfect echo :

```
// example of array :$array(1,2,3,4,5,etc);


Row 1 : unique
Row 2 : unique
Row 3 : duplicate col 2 = col 5, replacing col 2 with " unique number from array " .The row is now unique and updated ;
```

I tried :

```
$search_data = mysqli_query("select * from mestesug where id != 0 "))
while ($select_data = mysqli_fetch_array($search_data))
{for(i=1 i=n i++)
 for(j=1 j=n j++)
SELECT * FROM mestesug WHERE COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 IN 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM mestesug );
If $select_data['col1'] == $select_data['col2']
echo 'Duplicate' else echo 'Unique';}
```

It doesn't work .. help Please :)

Comment: Your `for` statements are incorrect. You could always try having a look at the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php Well lets start with the for loop anyway.

Comment: 1. See normalization. It is THE fundamental concept of relational databases.

Comment: i will try to modify the code but still i had some issue about calling them and search for the colomns on each row, can you provide me an simple code that can do a part of my request?. Thank you